# Check which images are used on website (in both HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have taken over a site which has two huge image folders (199 images altogether). I want to optomize the images, but only the images that are actually used on the site. Is there any way that I can check / download only the images that are used (including used in CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure for css,if it would work,

try this

```
 function img_find() {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var imgSrcs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
        }

        return imgSrcs;
    }
```

or this

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

or even this

```
var srcList = $('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

**but this would work for a page**

Answer (score 0):

Use a site grabber...it will search each page of the site and download the images (you have options for what to download, when using IDM). Further you can limit the depth of links followed or which links to exclude etc.